# ASP.Net MVC controller route when large records

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application I have a page that displays a list of records and with every record there is a link to click for more details of that record. It goes to the other controller. 
Let me tell a sequence. From 'ToDoListSelect' controller it goes to 'ToDoList' and on clicking the link from ToDoList it goes to 'Info' controller. Everything works fine on my development machine with same database as on the server. 
Now, I put the package on server and there it works okay if the records on the page are less than 500 or so. If there are more records then from ToDoList it does not go to Info but throws exception and I see it's going to ToDoListSelect which is weird. I do not know where to start looking for the problem. Any suggestions? Any details needed just let me know.

Here are the routes in my application:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{ 
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
    routes.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
    ); 
} 

protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); 
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
}
```

The error thrown is:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The operation is invalid because of the current state of the object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about this error, view and determine where the error originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Source Error:

During execution of the current web request An unhandled exception was generated. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
[InvalidOperationException: Der Vorgang ist aufgrund des aktuellen Zustands des Objekts ungültig.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +11485999
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +157
   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ReplaceCollection>b__e() +63
   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ReplaceCollection>b__11() +20
   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.DeferredCountArrayList.get_Count() +20
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +34
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +212
   System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProvider..ctor(ControllerContext controllerContext, IUnvalidatedRequestValues unvalidatedValues) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) +28
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +238
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +148
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +472
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +347
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +46
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +153
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +691
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Can you please put your routes and also any error messages that might have been thrown or logged.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Thanks Mr. Google!
http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2012/01/19/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of.aspx

Put the change in web.config and it works fine.